# Why is DbContext.SaveChangesAsync throwing a "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, sqlexception

The error in the title is occurring only in my QA environment right now, and not in my DEV environment. I've pointed my local machine towards the QA environment, ran a SQL trace, and can 1) reproduce the error and 2) see the actual SQL code being generated.

What I don't understand is how in the hell an error like this is even possible on an update? Here's my code:

```
            var investigation = await (
                        from  ti in DbContext.Investigation
                        where ti.Id == model.InvestigationId
                        select ti
                    ).SingleAsync();

            investigation.QueueId = model.QueueId;

            var result = await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return result;
```

I initially thought that first line (query) was returning more than one result, which would make sense. However, the error occurs on the `var result = await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` line. Could someone please point me in the right direction to resolve this? My SQL query as picked-up by SQL Server Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Investigation] SET [QueueId] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p1 bigint,@p0 smallint',@p1=7863,@p0=4
```

Comment: I suspect an update trigger which has a bug that is causing the error.

Comment: @Dan Guzman -- Holy crap THANK YOU. Please put your comment down as an answer and I'll happily accept it! So I have no idea how this happened, but a bunch of insert statements were somehow placed into my trigger, but AFTER the END keyword. Somehow this ONLY occurred in QA; doesn't exist in PROD or DEV. But deleting that garbage out of there fixed the issue!

Comment: @Dan Guzman -- Could you also detail in your answer how you thought up this as the cause of the problem?

Comment: The extraneous trigger code was probably because someone missed a GO batch terminator when changing the trigger so the rest of the batch was included in the trigger instead of be executed separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no subquery in this problem code as the error message suggests:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Investigation] SET [QueueId] = @p0
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
',N'@p1 bigint,@p0 smallint',@p1=7863,@p0=4
```

Consequently, the error must be in trigger code fired by the `UPDATE` statement.

I see from your comment that extraneous `INSERT` statements were inadvertently included in the trigger code. A more common cause of these symptoms is that the trigger is improperly coded as to expect a single row to be affected. A trigger fires once per statement, not per row, so it is important that trigger code handle the possibility of multiple rows.